# Genomics: Downloading genomic data from the NCBI Genbank database

Tags: genomics, phylogenetics, genbank

I'm taking a genomics course at school, and we have a final project due in a few weeks. 
Now, I can write bash scripts to sort and analyze the data, etc. However, I'm not quite sure how to actually *get* the data from the database. I was hoping to get some help there.

I'd like to get the assemblies of genomes for the species in the *Borrelia* genus. Is there any way that I can do this using commands like "wget", for example. I'm not even sure what URL I'd have to give the computer to go fetch these. Then once I give it the correct URL, how should I tell it what file in that directory to download?

I'd greatly appreciate some help on this issue.

Comment: Have you tried Google on something like _Borrelia genome?_  I've never done it before but it took me less than 10 minutes to find the genome for a borrelia species from that point.

Comment: @mgkrebbs - I'm sorry, but I forgot to mention in my post, that I need the genomes for many species of Borrelia. I wanted to know that, instead of doing it manually, is there some way I could get the computer to download the assemblies for all the Borrelia species in Genbank?

Comment: [Entrez](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK25501/) is what you want for this, most likely. There are R/python packages that can also access it pretty easily (biomaRt/biopython, respectively).

Comment: Do you need the assembly information and metadata? or do you need the genomes sequences themselves?

Comment: @mgkrebbs Getting data off of NCBI is infuriatingly difficult and non-obvious, if you don’t know *exactly* what you’re looking for. *Finding* the data is one thing (already not quite as easy as you make it sound). And then …?!

Answer (score 3):

For downloading data from commandline use the [E-utilities](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK25500/) of NCBI.

Comment: Can you edit your answer to provide an example query to download all of the Borrelia genomes from NCBI using the tool that you linked?

Comment: @conchoecia I answered this in [biology.se] and therefore did not go into details. I'll provide an example as soon as I can.

Comment: @WYSIWYG could you provide a link to your answer in Biology?